# Reactive mat-datepicker formatting using luxon

Tags: momentjs, luxon, mat-datepicker

I'm trying to replace momentjs with luxonjs which is used in mat-datepicker of a reactive form, initially I'm loading the datepicker field with ISO format

> '2022-05-10T10:34:31.311-04:00'

for which I used below luxon formatting to save the values

> DateTime.fromISO(
> this.form?.get('date')?.value
> ).toISODate();
>
> DateTime.fromISO(this.form?.get('date')?.value)
> .plus({ day: 1 })
> .toISODate();

When I select different date, the date format is different from my original

> Sun May 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

How to change this format to ISO using luxon

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with a workaround by converting the reactive form date value to ISO format using angular DatePipe

```
let date = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(
  this.form?.get('date')?.value,
  'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'
); 
date = DateTime.fromISO(date).plus({ day: 1 }).toISODate();
```